# how to deploy react isomorphic app to any server?

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, isomorphic

I am working on a react isomorphic app in which my express server is running along with the client app now I want to deploy this app but didn't know the proper way to deploy this kind of app.

[image]

this boilerplate of my project client folder contains react app and server.js contain express server. normally we run the build command and deploy our project's build. but in this case, if I run the build command then I lose my server.

[image]

my react app is running on 3000 port while my server is running on 5000.

if anyone has the solution or gives a bit of advice.

I need to get data from google bigquery and it is not possible from the client-side so use this approach

Comment: You have to setup your proxy ssrver that runs in 5000

Comment: proxy is set to 5000 port. and everything is working perfectly on localhost the problem is how to deploy this kind of app

Comment: For that you have to setup the same proxy servers in the machines that you going to deploy. in my case i use proxy because of cors issue.